# FineTune GPT2 on Insurance Domain data

Tags: dns, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2, fine-tuning

I am new to LLM and I am trying to finetune GPT2 from Huggingface on Insurance domain data. I am not getting results from the Trained data instead I am getting different results.

My Training Data is a word document (The content is not like Question and Answer).

Example: When I asked the question "What is Insurance mean?" I got different results. The finetuned GPT2 model gave different answer which is not in my Training Data. How can i make my finetuned model to throw answers from my Training data?